# Manually get knockout to re-evaluate a dependantObservable

Tags: validation, knockout.js, ko.dependentobservable

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have a scenario where I have a validation system which notifies my validation system when something has become valid/invalid via a dependant observable. Now this works great when a user is filling out a form as the dependantObservable is driven off the underlying observables value changing. (i.e if the Name property changes, it will re-evaluate the `isValid` dependant observable, which will in turn notify my binding which hooks into the validation system).

Now my problem is that if the user doesn't touch the form at all and just goes straight to submission, it will not trigger the binding, as the underlying values have not changed for any observables, so no subscribers will  know about any validation changes happening. Ideally I do not want to go through each observable and re-assign it its current variable to push a validation evaluation through, which would in turn trigger a change in the validation state. So as really all I want to do is get this `isValid` dependantObservable to *refresh* for lack of a better word.

It seems quite nasty either way, but my options seem to be either:

1) Force a value change on all observables being validated against (horrible)
2) Force a re-evaluation of the isValid dependantObservable to trigger the subscriber (less horrible, but still bad)
3) Re-write the validation library to expose a `forceValidation()` function which would somehow trigger everything to be re-evaluated, bypassing the need for the underlying observables to trigger the validation pipeline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

On your computed observable (`isValid`) you can call `notifySubscribers(currentValue)`, which will notify any subscribers with the current value.  It will not re-evaluate the computed and will simply notify subscribers with the current value.

Comment: Oh brilliant, I was also told that ``notifySubscribers(currentValue)`` woudl do the job, but if this one does not require the read first it is a better solution. thanks!

Comment: valueHasMutated will send the current value stored internally in the observable, while notifySubscribers will send whatever value that you pass as the first arg (which would require you to read the current value in your case).

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Has anything changed regarding the way that this works?  On 2.3.0 I get the error `Object ... has no method 'valueHasMutated'`, whereas calling `myComputed.notifySubscribers(myComputed())` gives me no such error...

Comment: `ko.computed` is "inherited" from `ko.subscribable` and not `ko.observable`. That is why it has `notifySubscribers` method. As to `valueHasMutated` - it has no such method (to be concise in version 3.1.0), in fact `notifySubscribers` is called internally within `ko.computed` in `evaluateImmediate` function.

Answer (score 4):

Add binding `enable: formValid` where `formValid = ko.computed(return true if all values are valid)` to submit button. This way user can not submit until form is filled properly.

Use `ko.validation.validateObservable(yourDependentObservable)` to revalidate field manually

or use `yourObsevable.notifySubscribers()` if `yourDependentObservable` depends on `yourObservable`.