# Swap 2 items in observableArray - knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observablecollection, knockout-2.0

im tring to Replace between 2 items in observableArray with knockout  but something is wrong..

after the replace of the items ,i will change and send the displayOrder property (in both itmems) to the server (or should i take other approach for this)

```
        ReplaceBetweenTwoitemsInArray: function () {
            console.log("ranking down msg");
            var currentItemindex = viewModel.myobservableArray.indexOf(this); 
            var nextItemIndex = currentItemindex + 1;
            viewModel.myobservableArray .replace(
                 viewModel.myobservableArray ()[nextItemIndex], 
                viewModel.myobservableArray ()[currentItemindex]
             );

        }
```

only the first item changed to the second item but the second item doesnt become the first one

Comment: What is the "something" that is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what viewModel.messages is, but invoking it (with the "()") seems queer as it looks like beeing an array or string.

Comment: `replace` doesn't do a swap. Why are you using two arrays (`myobservableArray` and `messages`)? Is the order different in the two arrays?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258086/how-do-i-swop-2-items-in-an-observablearray/10630319#10630319

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Paoli's answer, but will also trigger updates to observables, could be DRYer.

http://jsfiddle.net/marrok/ckMJE/101/

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: colors">
    <li><span data-bind="text:color"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
<br/>
<span>From:</span><input type="text" data-bind="value:from"/>
<br/>
<span>TO:</span><input type="text" data-bind="value:to"/>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click:swap">Swap It</button>​
```

Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.self = this;
    self.from = ko.observable(0); // default
    self.to = ko.observable(1); // default
    self.colors = ko.observableArray([{
        color: 'red'},
    {
        color: 'green'},
    {
        color: 'pink'},
    {
        color: 'blue'},
    {
        color: 'yellow'}]);

    self.swap= function() {
        var iTo = parseInt(self.to());
        var iFrom = parseInt(self.from());
        var from = self.colors()[iFrom];
        var to = self.colors()[iTo];
        console.log("Before", self.colors().map(function(d){return d.color;} ), from, to, iFrom, iTo)
        self.colors()[iTo] = from;
        self.colors()[iFrom] = to;
        console.log("After ", self.colors().map(function(d){return d.color;} ), from, to, iFrom, iTo)
        self.colors.valueHasMutated()

    };
};
model = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(model);​
```

Comment: Does the trick for me! Only caveat was that it doesn't work if you are using DataTables to render the array as a table, particularly with a binding handler, rather than doing a straight data-bind as per the example here. I removed the DataTable and now this code works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary variable:

```
var arr = ko.observableArray([0, 1])

// Should produce arr() = [0, 1]

var tmp = arr()[0];

arr()[0] = arr()[1];
arr()[1] = tmp;

// At this point, arr() is [1, 0]
```

Comment: very clean and simple. but you need to tell knockout that the observableArray's value has changed manually:

`arr.valueHasMutated()`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519333/manually-get-knockout-to-re-evaluate-a-dependantobservable#9519870

Answer (score 0):

You can just use remove and splice functions directly on the observableArray like this:

```
var arr=ko.observableArray(["x","y"]);
var index=arr.indexOf("y");
var tmp=arr()[index-1];
arr.remove(tmp);
arr.splice(index,0,tmp);
```