# knockout.js not updating observable through mapping plugin on second try

Tags: knockout.js

The `ko.mapping.fromJS(settings, self.settings);` doesn't seem to be updating my dynamic view a second time.  I believe its because the values are the same, so the subscription never gets fired to update the view again.  The view contains default values and are opened in a modal so you see the default values the second time. I execute `app.viewModel.members.eventSchedule.editSettings.settings.GameTime("204")` and it updates just fine if the value is different from the original one in the first call.  Can I execute the subscription for all the observables on that `self.settings` object after it remaps?  I know I could do valueHasMutated or assign an empty value and then the real value, but I dont want to do this for 10 properties.

This works

```
self.dialog.isOpen(true);
ko.mapping.fromJS(settings, self.settings);
self.settings.GameTime.valueHasMutated();
```

Javascript

```
function EditSettings() {
        var self = this;

        self.settings = null;

        self.dialog = new Dialog();
        self.open = function (open, url) {

            if (open) {
                var options = {
                    url: url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (settings) {
                        self.dialog.isOpen(true);
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(settings, self.settings);
                    }
                };

                app.call(options);
            } else {
                self.dialog.isOpen(false);
            }
        };
   }
```

Comment: Could you repro in a fiddle?

Comment: Not really, cause it's a special case and alot of JS and dynamic HTML so its quite hard to replicate it fiddle.  Like I said I know what the problem is, but is there a way to execute all observables to send out subscriptiosn on one object instead of using valueHasMutated?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean arent using the mapping plugin...

Comment: I see, that might not be such a big deal because its not used in any other situation.  How do you do that?  Another way is to iterate through the properties on that object, test if its an observable (which it always will be), and run valueHasMutated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manually get knockout to re-evaluate a dependantObservable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519333/manually-get-knockout-to-re-evaluate-a-dependantobservable)

Comment: This isnt already answered.  This has to do with manual subscriptions with the mapping plugin, the answer you referenced doesnt do with the mapping plugin.

Comment: The answer you posted as an answer also has nothing to do with the mapping plugin...  And it just creates more white noise on SO.com, ideally when users come to find an answer they find it quick instead of combing through duplicates like this question

Comment: I know it doesn't, if a person Googles the same issue I had they can see at the moment there isn't a better answer then doing it manually.  They would never know that from the answer you referenced, they would keep searching for an answer. That is why it is distinct and were you the one who down voted me?

Comment: There is a better answer, and I have linked to three already, but your way is a hack and not a direction that future users should use

Comment: You didnt give me one answer on how to do it with the mapping plugin, the answer you described was one from the link you mentioned.  Give me an answer for the mapping plugin, if not this is the only way around it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works like a charm.

```
self.dialog.isOpen(true);
ko.mapping.fromJS(settings, self.settings);

for (var property in self.settings) {
   self.settings[property].valueHasMutated();
}
```

Comment: Why would you down vote this? First the question then my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the party, but I had the same issue with knockout.mapping and used the accepted (but for some reason downvoted) solution. However I found that in my particular situation the mapping plug-in was adding a **ko_mapping** object to the properties that was not an observable (and thus had no .valueHasMutated to call). This may be an odd case (and I am working to clean up some of the observable calls) but it did show a potential exception in the code that can be avoided:

Here is what I did to avoid a non-observable causing an exception (using the variables from above to be consistent):

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(settings, self.settings);
        //Indicate mutated value for all properties
        for (var property in self.settings) {
            if (typeof (self.settings[property].valueHasMutated) === "function") {
                self.settings[property].valueHasMutated();
            }                
        }
```

That should be useful in cases where a non-observable property exists in a mapped observable.