# Is there a way to manually update observable in knockout 3.0?

Tags: knockout.js

I am looking for a way to manually update observable. I have checked the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519333/manually-get-knockout-to-re-evaluate-a-dependantobservable) but when I tried to do something like that, I was not able to achieve what I expected.

I need it for the following purpose. In my real code I have something similar to this (JS [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Jm3/3/) is included). The real code is much bigger and I tried to make a reproducible example, also it does not really represent the problem I am trying to fix:

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: changeLang">Change</button>
<div data-bind="foreach: last">
    <div data-bind="text: lang[$data]"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
lang = {1: "eine", 2: "zwei"};

function getRandomLang(){
    var tags = [
        {1 : 'one', 2 : 'two'},
        {1 : 'eine', 2 : 'zwei'}
    ];
    return tags[Math.round( Math.random() )];
}

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.last = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 2]);
    this.changeLang = function(){
        lang = getRandomLang();
        //self.last.valueHasMutated();
        console.log(lang);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

And I want it to change the language when the person click on the button. This is exactly why I want to update manually observable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `this.last(getRandomLang())`  ?

Comment: There are a few things about your example making it a little hard to see what it is you are really after, but I have setup a little fiddle showing an example of _one way_ to achieve what I think you are going for (there are of course many possible ways), trying to change very little from your code, which you can find at: http://jsfiddle.net/2VxNU/. If anything about it is unclear, I suggest you first go through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/ and then ask for clarifications if it is still unclear.

Comment: @robert.westerlund sorry for my lame example. I just created something to be able to describe what I want. Apparently it was not good. I wanted to manually change observable. Your example definitely works (thank you), but is there a way to manually update observable?

Comment: What do you mean with "manually update observable"? Which observable? The `last` observable? The fiddle I linked to does manually update the `lang` observable, so just do `self.last([1,2,1,1,2,1]);` or similar, to update the `last` observable. Again, go through the tutorials I linked to above (and [the knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) is also good, so reading it will probably also be a good suggestion); they will probably answer a lot of questions for you.

Comment: @robert.westerlund yes. I have an observable last. I wanted to manually trigger update on it. Sorry if it does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Didn't the code suggestions in my last comment work? If not, what errors do you get?

Comment: I have now also updated the fiddle to update the `last` observable; the changes can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/2VxNU/1/. But please, do go through the tutorials and the documentation.

Comment: I've read the question and the above comments, but I still have a hard time to see what "manually update observable" means. I think it would be good if you define that in the question itself, and try to be rather explicit about it. (My best guess would be that it just means changing an observable's value at some point in your own JS, but that's so trivial I doubt you meant that?)

Comment: @robert.westerlund thank you very much. It works. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You set your variable 'lang' as an observable

```
var lang = ko.observable({1: "eine", 2: "zwei"});
```

Then, in your method,

```
lang(getRandomLang());
```

That's how you update an observable. Knowing what you're trying to do would be much easier, since I'm not sure if this would give you the desired result. It'd change the value of lang, and update anything directly bound to lang, but most of the time observable properties wrap primitives that are used for display.

You'd want to create a model that represents your UI, where your data will be represented,. Then, you change those values when your data changes (via click, ajax call, etc...)